# Python tuples dictionary addition

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have a dictionary of tuples as follows:

```
tupledict = {('A','B','C'):2, ('A',): 3, ('B',) :4, ('C',): 5}
```

Currently, the first tuple is 2, however I want it to read values from the individual tuples to give me the correct sum of 12.

So output should be:

```
tupledict = {('A','B','C'):12, ('A',): 3, ('B',) :4, ('C',): 5}
```

How could this be done?

Comment: The moment you have to resort to iteration over a dictionary, you know you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
for key in list(tupledict):
    if len(key) > 1:
        tupledict[key] = sum(tupledict.get((subk,),0) for subk in key)
```

So we iterate over the list of keys (we use a `list(..)` such that we do not update a collection we are currently iterating over.

In case the `len(key)` is greater than 1, we calculate the sum of the subkeys, and assign that value to the `tupledict`.

This constructs the following dictionary:

```
>>> tupledict = {('A','B','C'):2, ('A',): 3, ('B',) :4, ('C',): 5}
>>> for key in list(tupledict):
...     if len(key) > 1:
...         tupledict[key] = sum(tupledict.get((subk,),0) for subk in key)
... 
>>> tupledict
{('A',): 3, ('B',): 4, ('C',): 5, ('A', 'B', 'C'): 12}
```

Alternatively, you can *subclass* the dictionary and override the `__getitem__` such that if one requests a tuple with length greater than 1, it adds the elements together. In this case we will save on memory (and do not have to updated all tuples) since the tuples `('A','B','C')` are stored *implicitly*:

```
class SumDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if len(key) > 1:
            return sum(self.get((subk,) ,0) for subk in key)
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(key)
```

For example:

```
>>> tupledict = {('A',): 3, ('B',) :4, ('C',): 5}
>>> sd = SumDict(tupledict)
>>> sd[('A','B','C')]
12
>>> sd[('A','B')]
7
```

Comment: might be safer to use `tupledict.get((subk,), 0)` in case of missing elements?

Comment: You migh consider sublass dict and ut this code in the   `__missing__` method for something really cool

Comment: @jsbueno: yes, but the question is about *fixing* the dictionary: the key is not missing, it is simply wrong.

Comment: So, subclass and redo the  `__getitem__` method instead of `__missing__`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary comprehension to build a new dict:

```
>>> tupledict = {('A','B','C'): 2, ('A',): 3, ('B',): 4, ('C',): 5}
>>> {t: sum(tupledict.get((x,), 0) for x in t) for t in tupledict}
{('A', 'B', 'C'): 12, ('A',): 3, ('B',): 4, ('C',): 5}
```

Using `tupledict.get()` instead of indexing handles the case when some 1-tuple is missing.